# SQL Injection Attack: What is this supposed to do?

Tags: mysql, sql-injection

I woke up to this in my error log

> [2018-04-14 00:58:26] production.ERROR: SQLSTATE[22001]: String data, right truncated: 1406 Data too long for column 'source' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `ad_clicks` (`ad_id`, `bout_id`, `source`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (6, 309031, app.home) AND 9957=(SELECT UPPER(XMLType(CHR(60)||CHR(58)||CHR(113)||CHR(113)||CHR(112)||CHR(122)||CHR(113)||(SELECT (CASE WHEN (9957=9957) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) FROM DUAL)||CHR(113)||CHR(107)||CHR(118)||CHR(107)||CHR(113)||CHR(62))) FROM DUAL) AND (9369=9369, 2018-04-14 00:58:26, 2018-04-14 00:58:26)) {"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\Database\QueryException(code: 22001): SQLSTATE[22001]: String data, right truncated: 1406 Data too long for column 'source' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `ad_clicks` (`ad_id`, `bout_id`, `source`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (6, 309031, app.home) AND 9957=(SELECT UPPER(XMLType(CHR(60)||CHR(58)||CHR(113)||CHR(113)||CHR(112)||CHR(122)||CHR(113)||(SELECT (CASE WHEN (9957=9957) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) FROM DUAL)||CHR(113)||CHR(107)||CHR(118)||CHR(107)||CHR(113)||CHR(62))) FROM DUAL) AND (9369=9369, 2018-04-14 00:58:26, 2018-04-14 00:58:26)) at /var/framework/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:664, Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException(code: 22001): SQLSTATE[22001]: String data, right truncated: 1406 Data too long for column 'source' at row 1 at /var/framework/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOStatement.php:107, PDOException(code: 22001): SQLSTATE[22001]: String data, right truncated: 1406 Data too long for column 'source' at row 1

And from what I can figure, someone tried injecting this through the `source` parameter.

> ) AND 9957=(SELECT UPPER(XMLType(CHR(60)||CHR(58)||CHR(113)||CHR(113)||CHR(112)||CHR(122)||CHR(113)||(SELECT (CASE WHEN (9957=9957) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) FROM DUAL)||CHR(113)||CHR(107)||CHR(118)||CHR(107)||CHR(113)||CHR(62))) FROM DUAL) AND (9369=9369

I'm basically curious what the attacker or code was supposed to do.

Comment: Can't work annyway `XMLType` isn't a MySQL function and pipelines to concat doesn't work in MySQL unless configured.. This look like a Oracle SQL injection attempt

Comment: I reformatted the question to use block-quote format instead of code format, because the lines were so long they were unreadable without lots of horizontal scrolling.

Comment: @RaymondNijland Thanks for the pointer. Saw a lot of its variations already stored in several rows in the database. Using PDO seems to have saved a lot but seeing all these injected rows is still a pain. Is there any "more secure" way to stop the attacks?

Comment: The usual fix, as far as I know, is to look in your logs for the IP address the attacker is sending these requests from, and block that IP address.

Comment: @BillKarwin ok. Thanks alot

Comment: and whois that ip and send a email (with the logs) to the ip provider abuse email address for brute force SQL injection hacking attemptes...

Comment: c/o Vladimir Putin